# 404 error for Google +1 button in web pages

Tags: html, google-plus-one

Hi I am new web development and php coding.I have implemented the google +1 for my web site, but when I clicked on it, it is showing error message "404. That’s an error.The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know". I am using the code that is provided in following http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Comment: A quick google search brings up this http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=33a8f8436008f516&hl=en

Comment: We really need to see some code to be able to help ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you really put whatever you wanted the +1-button for inside the tags? A 404 would suggest that you just left the tags as they appear in the example. If you were to supply some sample code of whatever is now working, people on this site could help you out a lot better.

Comment: I am using the following code                              <g:plusone size="small"></g:plusone>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>                                                            But when I click on the button it turned red with ! mark.How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Again, this is not a very useful example of your code. This is pretty much just the code that is supplied by Google. You need to specify where you have pasted it and what you want to achieve. As it stands, there's no way that you can get any help from the way you've phrased your question. Sorry.

Comment: I finally figure out the issue. Everything is fine with placing the code that is supplied by Google but the thing is I was testing it with a private url which google does not validate it.